# Explanation of $\sigma$-weak topology von a von Neumann algebra

Tags: gn.general-topology, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra. I want to understand the precise meaning of the $\sigma$-weak topology on $A$. What I understand so far is the following: The $\sigma$-weak topology, which we will denote by $\tau$, is the weak$^*$-topology on $A$ (which can be defined since every von Neumann algebra has a (unique) predual $A_*$). It seems that $A_*$ is the Banach space of ultraweakly continuous linear functionals on $A$. But how to understand the ultraweak topology on $A$? Do one use the fact that $A$ is continuously embedded into some $B(H)$?

In addition I have also some other questions regarding the structure of the $\sigma$-weak topology:
Is the $\sigma$-weak topology a Hausdorff topology on $A$ and possibly sequentially complete on norm-bounded sets? Is this topology even norming on $A$, i.e., for all $x\in A$ one has that
$$
||x||=\sup_{\substack{\varphi\in(X,\tau)'\\||\varphi||\leq1}}{|\varphi(x)|}.
$$
Probably these questions are all trivial to answer, however it would be great to have some references. Could you help me with this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This isn't research level, but yes, every von Neumann algebra can be realized as a weak* closed subalgebra of some $B(H)$, and its weak* topology is the inherited weak* topology. That should answer your other questions too,

Comment: Regarding references: my **guess** is that Kadison+Ringrose's 2-volume book would explain the relationship between these topologies, but I don't have a copy at hand to check. There might also be something in Murphy's book on Cstar algebras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really research level, and is probably better suited to math.stackexchange, but here's an answer anyway. I will take as given that you know the notation $\sigma(E^*,E)$ for the weak-* topology on $E^*$, or more generally $\sigma(F,E)$ on a Banach space $F$ isomorphic to the dual space of a Banach space $E$.

For any Hilbert space $\newcommand{\Hil}{\mathcal{H}}\Hil$, the space of bounded operators $B(\Hil)$ is isomorphic to the dual space of the space of trace-class operators $B_*(\Hil)$ by the pairing $\langle T, \rho \rangle = \mathrm{tr}(T\rho)$, for $T \in B(\Hil)$ and $\rho \in B_*(\Hil)$. The weak-* topology $\sigma(B(\Hil),B_*(\Hil))$ on $B(\Hil)$ can be called the $\sigma$-weak or ultraweak topology, according to the author's preference, *i.e.* these are two names for the same thing.

When we have a C$^*$-algebra $A$ that is isometrically isomorphic to the dual space of a Banach space $A_*$, then we say it is a W$^*$-algebra, and the weak-* topology $\sigma(A,A_*)$ is also called the $\sigma$-weak or ultraweak topology.

If $A \subseteq B(\Hil)$ is a von Neumann algebra, then we can consider the restriction of $\sigma(B(\Hil),B_*(\Hil))$ to $A$. We can then define the space $A_*$ to be the set of linear functionals continuous in this topology. It is then a (nontrivial) theorem, that $A_*$ is a closed subspace of $A^*$, and $A$ is isomorphic to the dual space of $A_*$ under the restriction of the double dual embedding, and the topologies $\sigma(B(\Hil),B_*(\Hil))$ and $\sigma(A,A_*)$ agree on $A$, justifying why they're both called the $\sigma$-weak/ultraweak topology.

The questions in your second paragraph are all consequences of being a weak-* topology (the Banach-Alaoglu theorem implies that weak-* closed norm-bounded sets are complete, because they're compact).

I hope this helps you to understand standard references like Takesaki's *Theory of Operator Algebras*, Dixmier's *Von Neumann Algebras*, Kadison and Ringrose's *Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras*.